# How to use Contour_To_GeoJson?

Tags: geojson, contour, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert a matplotlib contourf to geojson, but i'm stuck.
I created contourf from a csv.

Here's my code :

```
data = np.genfromtxt('centroid.csv', delimiter=',')
x = data[..., 0]
y = data[..., 1]
z = data[..., 2]
xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 200)
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)

nb_class = 3

collec_poly = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, nb_class, vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max())

geojson = geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson(contour=collec_poly, contour_levels=nb_class, geojson_filepath='out.geojson', ndigits=3, unit='m')
```

it returns me this error :

```
assert len(contour_levels) == len(collections)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I can't really understand all needed arguments for **contour_to_geojson** and I didn't find a good documentation.

Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use the same simple example as in [Converting Matplotlib contour objects to Shapely objects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/100002)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]
m = [[15,14,13,12],[14,12,10,8],[13,10,7,4],[12,8,4,0]]
figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
contourf = ax.contourf(x,y,m, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

[image]

With basic [geojsoncontour](https://github.com/bartromgens/geojsoncontour)

```
import geojsoncontour
geojson = geojsoncontour.contourf_to_geojson(contourf=contourf)
d = json.loads(geojson)
for i in d['features']:
     print i

{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[4.0, 3.5], [4.0, 4.0], [3.5, 4.0], [4.0, 3.5]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'stroke-opacity': 1, u'title': u'0.00 ', u'fill-opacity': 0.9, u'stroke': u'#0000c8', u'stroke-width': 1, u'fill': u'#0000c8'}}
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.5], [3.5, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'stroke-opacity': 1, u'title': u'2.00 ', u'fill-opacity': 0.9, u'stroke': u'#0040ff', u'stroke-width': 1, u'fill': u'#0040ff'}}
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[4.0, 2.5], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [2.5, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33333], [3.33333, 3.0], [4.0, 2.5]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'stroke-opacity': 1, u'title': u'4.00 ', u'fill-opacity': 0.9, u'stroke': u'#00c0ff', u'stroke-width': 1, u'fill': u'#00c0ff'}}
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[4.0, 2.0], [4.0, 2.0], [4.0, 2.5], [3.33333, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33333], [2.5, 4.0], [2.0, 4.0], [2.0, 4.0], [2.0, 4.0], [2.66667, 3.0], [3.0, 2.66667], [4.0, 2.0], [4.0, 2.0]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'stroke-opacity': 1, u'title': u'6.00 ', u'fill-opacity': 0.9, u'stroke': u'#49ffad', u'stroke-width': 1, u'fill': u'#49ffad'}}
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[3.0, 2.0], [4.0, 1.5], [4.0, 2.0], [4.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.66667], [2.66667, 3.0], [2.0, 4.0], [2.0, 4.0], [1.5, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'stroke-opacity': 1, u'title': u'8.00 ', u'fill-opacity': 0.9, u'stroke': u'#b1ff46', u'stroke-width': 1, u'fill': u'#b1ff46'}}
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.5], [3.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0], [1.5, 4.0], [1.0, 4.0], [1.0, 4.0], [1.33333, 3.0], [2.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 1.33333], [4.0, 1.0]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'stroke-opacity': 1, u'title': u'10.00 ', u'fill-opacity': 0.9, u'stroke': u'#ffd000', u'stroke-width': 1, u'fill': u'#ffd000'}}
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[2.0, 1.0], [2.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.33333], [2.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0], [1.33333, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0], [1.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 1.0]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'stroke-opacity': 1, u'title': u'12.00 ', u'fill-opacity': 0.9, u'stroke': u'#ff5900', u'stroke-width': 1, u'fill': u'#ff5900'}}
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'stroke-opacity': 1, u'title': u'14.00 ', u'fill-opacity': 0.9, u'stroke': u'#c40000', u'stroke-width': 1, u'fill': u'#c40000'}}
```

Now you can modify:

1) the [contour](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) or [contourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) arguments  as in your example
2) the geojson properties elements in the declaration

```
geom = [i for i in  d['features']]
geom[4]['properties']['stroke-width']
1
# modify stroke_with for example
geojson = geojsoncontour.contourf_to_geojson(contourf=contourf,stroke_width=5)
d = json.loads(geojson)
geom = [i for i in  d['features']]
geom[4]['properties']['stroke-width']
5
```

You can also use [tricontour](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour.html) and [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html)

```
import geopandas
# read point shapefile
points = gpd.read_files("points.shp")
points['x'] = points.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.x)
points['y'] = points.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.y)
# contouring x,y, z with tricontourf
cnt = ax.tricontourf(points.x, points.y,points.elev)
geojson = geojsoncontour.contourf_to_geojson(contourf=cnt, unit="m")
contours = json.loads(geojson)
# create resulting shapefile
result  = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(contours['features'])
result.to_file("contours.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to follow your post but I'm stuck with `geojson = geojsoncontour.contourf_to_geojson(contourf=contourf)` It returns me `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'contourf_to_geojson'`

Comment: Look at  [geojsoncontour: example_contourf.py](https://github.com/bartromgens/geojsoncontour/blob/master/examples/example_contourf.py)